# "Redirecting to..." middle page in redirections LARAVEL 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I have a very rare problem in Laravel 5.2

When i redirect from one URL to another it shows an intermediate page like this:

---

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type:  text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location:      [URLEXAMPLE.COM]
Set-Cookie: new_session=a21c4b1e34cb6add684f7a43561ee59c9ab6a0e0; expires=Thu, 30-Jul-2325 07:37:10 GMT; path=/; httponly

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=[URLEXAMPLE.COM]" />

        <title>Redirecting to [URLEXAMPLE.COM]</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to [URLEXAMPLE.COM]>.
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
  public function test1(){
    return redirect()->to('/test2');
  }

  public function test2(){
    echo "hi";
  }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('test1', 'TestController@test1')->name('test1');
Route::get('test2', 'TestController@test2')->name('test2');
```

In a clean installation of laravel 5.2 this dont happen.

Does anyone comes up with something?

thanks guys!

Comment: gif: https://gyazo.com/452d5654b6a463b9653d88cc500caaf0

Comment: Set-Cookie: 30-Jul-2325  ?  :) **Redirecting To Named Routes** https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects

Answer (score 0):

your method call is wrong, according to the doc you should do this

```
    return redirect()->route('test2');
  }
```

doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes